# how to remove empty lines from a file in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

how to remove empty lines from a file in Robot framework. m using Ride. I have removed commented lines but could not remove empty lines.

Below the file contents are:

Settings.User = abc Settings.Password = 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code which can be used to remove blank lines from file:

```
*** Test Case ***
first test
${contents}=Get File data.txt
Create File data2.txt    @{lines}=Split to lines ${contents}
:FOR  ${line} IN  @{lines}
\    ${length}=  GetLength ${line}
\    Run Keyword if  ${length} != 0\    Append To File  data2.txt  ${line}\n
```